# mingew32-g++.exe stopped working in CodeBlocks

Tags: gcc

I am using CodeBlocks in Windows 10 64-bit. It says 'mingew32-g++.exe' stopped working every time I want to build my code. I have tried reinstalling CodeBlocks many times.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file to mingw32-g++ : Go to `C:\mingew32\bin` -> find a file with -g++ at the end, make sure to save the current name for a backup file, then rename it to mingw32-g++. After that check to see if there's anything with -g++ at the end in `C:\mingw64\bin`.

If renaming to mingw32-g++ doesn't work, the next place to check would be in Programs and Features to find which program installed mingew32-g++.exe. You don't need to uninstall that program in order to check if it has a legitimate looking name. If it also looks wrong in Programs and Features, you can uninstall it, download it again and reinstall it.